# Xscreen saver not locking user

Tags: xscreensaver

In my new installation of Xscreen saver, it does not lock out the user when the screen saver kicks in. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
timeout:    0:03:00
cycle:      0:10:00
lock:       True       <--------LOOKS GOOD HERE
lockTimeout:    0:03:00   <--------LOOKS GOOD HERE
passwdTimeout:  0:00:30
visualID:   default
installColormap:    True
verbose:    False
timestamp:  True
splash:     True
splashDuration: 0:00:05
demoCommand:    xscreensaver-demo
prefsCommand:   xscreensaver-demo -prefs
nice:       10
memoryLimit:    0
fade:       True
unfade:     True
fadeSeconds:    0:00:02
fadeTicks:  20
captureStderr:  True
ignoreUninstalledPrograms:False
font:       *-medium-r-*-140-*-m-*
dpmsEnabled:    False
dpmsQuickOff:   False
dpmsStandby:    2:00:00
dpmsSuspend:    2:00:00
dpmsOff:    4:00:00
grabDesktopImages:  False
grabVideoFrames:    False
chooseRandomImages: False
imageDirectory:
```

Comment: `it does not lock out the user when the screen saver kicks in` ? You should wait another 3 minutes after kicks in, because your `lockTimeout:    0:03:00` above means "start locking after 3 minutes of screen saver kicks in", unless you change it to `00:00:00` which means locking as soon as screen saver kicks in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man xscreensaver-demo:

```
   Lock Screen After
       This  controls  the length of the ``grace period'' between when the
       screensaver activates, and when the  screen  becomes  locked.   For
       example,  if this is 5 minutes, and Blank After is 10 minutes, then
       after 10 minutes, the screen would blank.  If there was user activ‐
       ity  at  12  minutes, no password would be required to un-blank the
       screen.  But, if there was user activity at  15  minutes  or  later
       (that  is, Lock Screen After minutes after activation) then a pass‐
       word would be required.  The default is 0, meaning that if  locking
       is  enabled, then a password will be required as soon as the screen
       blanks.
```

Comment: There is no `Lock Screen After` and no `Blank After` in his config file.  Different versions?

Comment: They're the same. https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html