# How to make sure that screensaver does not kick in when watching a movie?

Tags: debian, xscreensaver, mpv

When you are watching a movie, many a times, the xscreensaver kicks in after sometime. Is there a way to tell xscreensaver not to kick in when watching a movie ?

Somebody told me and I tried this -

```
[$] alias mpv                                                                                                                       
mpv=$'mate-session-inhibit --inhibit\n/usr/bin/mpv'
```

This used to work but now doesn't. have no ideas why. Can somebody explain the above command as well.

This is xscreensaver is stacked up -

```
 5  timeout:    0:05:00
 6  cycle:      0:02:00
 7  lock:       True
 8  lockTimeout:    0:05:00
 9  passwdTimeout:  0:00:30
```

So, if I'm reading it right, it seems it says the actual timeout is around 10 mins, see [Xscreen saver not locking user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323477/xscreen-saver-not-locking-user#comment569012_323477) for xscreensaver reading.

Update - I am running/using mpv 0.23 on Debian testing/stretch.

Comment: Normally the movie viewer would tell the X server to disable the screensaver. I have no idea why this wouldn't work for you.

Comment: It is an issue in MATE I believe. See https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-screensaver/issues/91 and https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-screensaver/issues/57

Comment: What application are you playing your videos in?

Comment: @JacobVlijm in mpv, a cli player https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/releases lots of keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Ah, sorry should have seen that. We *could* add a small background script, looking once per minute or so if `mpv` is running, pressing a meaningless Ctrl press if so, to set idle time to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `heartbeat-cmd="/usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -deactivate > /dev/null"`
in .config/mpv/config at the bottom.

But this option will get Deprecated in newer Version [mpv github](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/releases)

Comment: I Updated my query with giving the version at my end. The heartbeat-cmd seems to have been deprecated at 0.18 itself so 0.23 is long ways off,  sorry.

Comment: check with ` mpv --list-options` if something  digestible is for you.  I use mpv 0.8.3 so it still working. :D

Comment: yup, tried it and still it works, it does give the warning though.

Comment: Disabled in deb10/buster. `Option --heartbeat-cmd was removed: use Lua scripting instead`

Answer (score 2):

#### Workaround

***If*** it is a bug, as you mention in a comment, you might use a small workaround to fix it.

If you run the small script below in the background (start it a few seconds after log in), it will prevent the screensaver to be triggered *if* and while `mpv` is running.

#### The script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
sleep 60
if [ -n "$(pgrep mpv)" ]; then
 xdotool key Ctrl
fi
done
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs [xdotool](http://man.cx/xdotool) to be on your system.
2. Then, simply copy the script into an empty file, start it on log in.

#### What it does

Practically nothing. Only once per minute, it checks if `mpv` is running, taps the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key if so, to make sure idle time is set to zero.

#### Note

As mentioned in a comment, the script can be used without any changes in `zsh`, ***however*** if you run it as an executable script (calling the interpreter from the shebang), change the shebang into `#!/bin/zsh`.

Comment: Would the script be much different in zsh ? And btw debian has xdotool, see https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/xdotool

Comment: @shirish a quick test seems to show the script can be run without any changes *but* the shebang, if it is executable. Simply replace the shebang with: `#!/bin/zsh`

Comment: @shirish just curious, but did you try?

Comment: not really, because my issue was solved with Bahamut's solution for now. I try to avoid scripts as the script depends on things remaining the same. If any of the packages do a change, it is highly likely the script may stop working. I still upped you as you made me aware of the tool xdotool which I wasn't aware of before.

Comment: @shirish thanks! I will be highly surprised if either xdotool or bash/zsh would end working as it does for the next 10 or 15 years though. That's all that is functional in the scrip.

Comment: ah true, was thinking about the xdotool though when I wrote that because as I understand it, it basically triggers xdotool to do an imaginary CTRL key press every minute mpv is playing, which is clever. I wish there was a way to do two correct answers then would have awarded you both, but it is the way it is.

Comment: @shirish haha, thanks. *of course* you should pick what suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Why not switch it off? This is 2017 and you shouldn't need a screensaver!

Use the Mode drop-down and change it to "Disable Screen Saver."

Comment: what do you mean by use the mode drop-down and change it to "Disable Screen Saver." Can you elaborate what you mean by it.

Comment: Is it in your Menu? Preferences>Screensaver

Comment: There are actually two, mate-screensaver is off. I also have traditional xscreensaver package whose values I just shared with you up.

Comment: In aa Terminal input: xscreenserver-command -exit

Comment: Now are userscripts from gti/mpv-wiki are available. This one https://gist.github.com/elenril/f8ff9475a7882b7a16cdd723c7dce150  works for me in debian11 with mate-desktop.